# Epson Gt-S50 scanner

Tags: debian

I'm trying to get an Epson GT-S50 USB scanner working in LMDE 4 (Debian 10 Buster). I've downloaded/installed the (iscan-gt-s80-bundle-2.30.4.x64.deb.tar.gz) from Epson to no avail. I receive the following message:
"Could not send command to scanner. Check the scanner's status."
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Has your user account been added to `scanner` and/or `plugdev` groups?

`scanner` is the group that grants access to scanners specifically. `plugdev` grants access to hot-pluggable devices in general, and is important to many USB-connected devices that use drivers implemented in user-space, which is how most USB scanner drivers are.

If you're not a member of these groups, use `usermod -a -G scanner,plugdev your_username_here` and then logout & login again. Note that there must be no space after the comma.

Comment: I did as instructed to no avail...any other suggestions? THX